# Why the ul selector doesn't work in linked CSS file?

Tags: css, html, css-selectors

I wanted to make a navigation bar using the following code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body class="background">
<ul>
<li>Home</li>
<li>News</li>
<li>Contact</li>
<li>About</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

And used the following code in *styles.css* document.

```
body.background {
  background-color: #333333;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

While the `background` class works perfectly fine the `ul` selector doesn't work at all. It changes when I put the CSS code in `<style></style>`. I expected bullets to disappear from the list. Now it looks like that.

- Home
- News
- Contact
- About

Comment: what is the expected behaviors?

Comment: Seems to work: https://jsfiddle.net/vy6ptnmj/140/ - maybe you just linked to it improperly? Try pressing CTRL+U on your browser and click on the linked CSS file to see if it linked properly.

Comment: There is nothing in the code you've presented that would cause the bullets to show in a modern browser. You may want to retype the code into a fresh text file and save over the existing one. There may be some unprintable characters interfering. Do you have any errors or warnings in your console?

Comment: Did you try clearing your browser cache? or run on another browser?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```css
.background {
  background-color: #eee;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body class="background">
<ul>
  <li>Home</li>
  <li>News</li>
  <li>Contact</li>
  <li>About</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm not sure what you're expecting.. but I can barely see the  list items with a dark background. Seems to be working fine (no bullets).

**OR**

You can keep your background color the same, just changed your ul color to white so it's easier to see.

```css
.background {
  background-color: #333333;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body class="background">
<ul>
  <li>Home</li>
  <li>News</li>
  <li>Contact</li>
  <li>About</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't think copy/paste of the code may be an answer. Not even the change of background ...

Comment: I still see the bullets. It didn't change annything.

Comment: @Baro Are we supposed to answer the questions in the comments? Sorry, didn't know - I'm not being sarcastic either, I don't know the meta of stack that well.

Comment: @noob What browser are you using to view your page? You may have to clear cache.

Comment: Well, the snippets don't recreate the issue either, since the CSS is inserted into a `<style>` tag, not a `<link>`.

Comment: Tip:  Use Divs - stop trying to alter the behaviour of UL

Comment: @Bryner If your answer is to change the background don't seems to be a complete answer, just a comment in my opinion.

Comment: @Baro just trying to help the guy. I can delete my answer but figured it would be an easy way for the user to see a quick code snippet preview. Just trying to help the guy, I don't care about the points. If someone else has the answer, put it up.

Comment: @Bryner It's just a suggestion. Leave your answer as it is. As a personal rule, when the question is resolvable with a small correction or is due to a typing problem, or similar, I prefer comments.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <style>
        .background{
            background:#333;
        }
        ul{
            list-style-type: none;
            color:white;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body class="background">
    <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>News</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
        <li>About</li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```